# Changing URLs in a SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3.5 million lines of URLs in a table.

Eg `http://value/value/value/value/value/value/value/value/value/VALUE I WANT`

There are always 11 `/` before the value I actually want.  How do I script something to change all rows?

Comment: And to what exactly do you want to change the column value?

Comment: I'm using MSSQL.  Yes I ant to change the column value

Comment: We know you want to change the column value. **To what**,was the question.

Comment: OK so I have the following URL: http://1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10.pdf
I want the new value to only be 10.pdf

Comment: "VALUE I WANT" is the last value in URL? Can be something like ".../VALUE I WANT/value/value/value...."?

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2cdc14/2)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (URL varchar(255))
INSERT INTO MyTable (URL) VALUES ('http://value/value/value/value/value/value/value/value/value/MYVALUE'),
                         ('1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10.pdf'),('1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/13TEST.pdf')
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT right(URL, charindex('/', reverse(URL)) - 1) AS MyVal from MyTable
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2cdc14/2/0)**:

```
|      MyVal |
|------------|
|    MYVALUE |
|     10.pdf |
| 13TEST.pdf |
```